# Speeding up comparison of doubles in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, double, binary-search

I have a function that uses binary search to find the index in a sorted array of doubles such that a "search value" is greater than or equal to the value in the array at that index but strictly less than the value in the array at the subsequent index, if sorted ascending. The input array can be sorted ascending or descending.

I have profiled my code on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 which shows that 12% of the time is spent in this function while 8% of the time is spent doing a comparison between the "search value" and a value in the array. I would like to explore the possibility of speeding up this function.

```
/**
    Binary Search algorithm for a sorted array of doubles
    _sortedArr could be sorted ascending or descending
    Find the index in the array _sortedArr such that:
    _sortedArr[lowerIndex] <= _valToFind < _sortedArr[lowerIndex+1]
*/
size_t findInArray(const double _sortedArr[], size_t _len, double _valToFind)
{
    size_t startIndex = 0;

    if( _len <= 1 ) return startIndex;

    // Determine if the array is sorted ascending or descending
    unsigned int isAscending = (_sortedArr[_len-1] > _sortedArr[startIndex]);

    // To avoid looping through the array, detect edge cases first
    if( isAscending ) {
        if( _valToFind <  _sortedArr[startIndex+1] ) return startIndex;
        if( _valToFind >= _sortedArr[_len-1] ) return _len-1;
    } else {
        if( _valToFind >  _sortedArr[startIndex+1] ) return startIndex;
        if( _valToFind <= _sortedArr[_len-1] ) return _len-1;
    }

    size_t lowerIndex = startIndex + 1;
    size_t upperIndex = _len - 1; 
    size_t midIndex = 0;

    // Binary search loop
    while (upperIndex - lowerIndex > 1)
    {
        midIndex = (upperIndex + lowerIndex) >> 1; // (upperIndex+lowerIndex)/2

        // 8% of time spent executing the if-clause
        if (_valToFind >=  _sortedArr[midIndex] == isAscending)
            lowerIndex = midIndex;
        else
            upperIndex = midIndex;
    }

    return lowerIndex;
}
```

The following is a way to test this function:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const double arr[] = {-3.0000000000000000, -2.5714285714285716, -2.1428571428571432,
                      -1.7142857142857146, -1.2857142857142860, -0.85714285714285743,
                      -0.42857142857142888, -3.3306690738754696e-016, 0.42857142857142821,
                      0.85714285714285676, 1.2857142857142854, 1.7142857142857140,
                      2.1428571428571423, 2.5714285714285707, 2.9999999999999991};

    size_t index = findInArray(arr, 15, 0.0);
    std::cout << "Index is: " << index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the if-clause (8% of the time spent here) to use the less-than comparison, there is no noticeable performance improvement:

```
if (!(_valToFind <  _sortedArr[midIndex]) == isAscending)
```

The only difference in the disassembly with this change was the use of 'ja' rather than jb.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Measure, profile, measure!

Comment: Would this do better on codereview?  It seems like it would fit that stack exchange's style better.

Comment: @Numeri, yes I think this would be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: does it seem slow? Your logic looks fine (quick scan only). Why not re-implement using c++ standards of searching sorted vectors etc. JUst to get an idea of a 'good; perf. You should be able to beat c++ library since you can hadn-craft the code

Comment: Er, are those profiler results (the 12% & 8%) from that test code?  Or from when the function is used in something... a bit more substantial?

Comment: @timday The profiler results are from the full, normal run of a program that uses this function which is definitely more substantial.

Comment: First things first: Write correct code for the ascending and descending case (you might split the function into two). Having that, you might use some std::algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review. (no automatic migration)

Comment: @pm100: Only if you are optimising for specific inputs. If you're trying to "beat c++ library" for general algorithms, you will fail.

Comment: I agree: this is a _good_ question and I hope it fares well on CR, but it does seem to belong there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks folks! I'll post this on CR.

Comment: What compilation flags are you using? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit? Try to switch on more modern instruction sets. For example, `cmov` instructions help avoiding conditional branches. Also SSE2 double comparison instructions could bring some improvement.

Comment: What is the expected size of inputs? Are we talking few, hundreds, millions?

Comment: @IlyaPopov It is a 32-bit executable running on a 64-bit OS (Win 7) on Intel Xeon. I am using SSE2 (the default on Visual Studio is SSE2 which also enables the modern instruction sets, is my understanding).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps attempt to remove the conditional branch in the code.

```
size_t luIndex[2] = { startIndex + 1, _len - 1 };
size_t &lowerIndex = luIndex[0];
size_t &upperIndex = luIndex[1]; 
size_t midIndex = 0;

// Binary search loop
while (upperIndex - lowerIndex > 1)
{
    midIndex = (upperIndex + lowerIndex) >> 1; // (upperIndex+lowerIndex)/2
    luIndex[_valToFind >= _sortedArr[midIndex] != isAscending] = midIndex;
}

return lowerIndex;
```

Comment: I do like the nifty trick of avoiding the conditional branch however this didn't reduce the number of machine instructions, and as a result, the performance didn't improve.

Comment: Improving 8% of 12% wasn't going to give a big difference in performance anyway. If you suspect that branch decision is really a bottleneck, I think you will have to analyze your data set and see if you need a better search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of the comparisons out of the loop:

```
size_t findInArray(const double _sortedArr[], size_t _len, double _valToFind)
{
size_t startIndex = 0;

if( _len <= 1 ) return startIndex;

// Determine if the array is sorted ascending or descending
unsigned int isAscending = (_sortedArr[_len-1] > _sortedArr[startIndex]);
size_t lowerIndex = startIndex + 1;
size_t upperIndex = _len - 1;
size_t midIndex = 0;

// To avoid looping through the array, detect edge cases first
if( isAscending ) {
    if( _valToFind <  _sortedArr[startIndex+1] ) return startIndex;
    if( _valToFind >= _sortedArr[_len-1] ) return _len-1;

    // Binary search loop for isAscending == true
    while (upperIndex - lowerIndex > 1)
    {
        midIndex = (upperIndex + lowerIndex) >> 1; // (upperIndex+lowerIndex)/2
        if (_valToFind >=  _sortedArr[midIndex])
            lowerIndex = midIndex;
        else
            upperIndex = midIndex;
    }
} else {
    if( _valToFind >  _sortedArr[startIndex+1] ) return startIndex;
    if( _valToFind <= _sortedArr[_len-1] ) return _len-1;

    // Binary search loop for isAscending == false
    while (upperIndex - lowerIndex > 1)
    {
        midIndex = (upperIndex + lowerIndex) >> 1; // (upperIndex+lowerIndex)/2
        if (_valToFind >=  _sortedArr[midIndex])
            upperIndex = midIndex;
        else
            lowerIndex = midIndex;
    }
}

return lowerIndex;
}
```

Comment: Good point! I made this change and looked at the disassembly and the machine instructions went down from 11 to 5:      mov         eax,dword ptr [midIndex]  
    mov         ecx,dword ptr [_sortedArr]  
    movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [_valToFind]  
    comisd      xmm0,mmword ptr [ecx+eax*8]  
    jb          findInArray+13Ch (03261ECh)